# How to load joined table in SQLAlchemy where joined table does not provide foreign key(relationship) in ORM

Tags: asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I have tables like below

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

class A(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)

class B(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    a_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
```

and has query:

```python
# Basic query
query = sa.select(B).join(A, A.id == B.a_id)
result = await session.execute(query)
results = result.scalars().all()
```

How should I change to get desired result?

```python
query = sa.select(B).join(A, A.id == B.a_id)
result = session.execute(query)
results = result.scalars().all()

# Problem
# SOME_KEY should be indicated in query as loading column
# SOME_KEY's type should be A class
# I want below thing

results[0].SOME_KEY.name # it should give joined `A` entity's property value
```

I have read documentation, have seen [loading techniques](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html), but could not find solution , it is mostly for relations.

Comment: You can create relationships without foreign keys.  Is there a reason not to do that in this situation?

Comment: I want to implement fast update where I will delete all items, then will do bulk insert

Comment: Can you just do an upsert instead of deleting everything ?

Comment: Good point, but for this case I have to do iterate over items to make upsert. It means if there is 10 items, it means 10 request to database, if 100 it is 100. Moreover, if there is an indexing, it will be slow for each upsert. That is why the fastest way is to delete all items, and bulk insert by existing primary keys(if not get default ones). As I remember, it won't delete indexes when record is deleted, it will be deleted while vacuuming, so it will be somehow faster. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Depending on db I think you can upsert from a select or from list of values.  I don't know anything about indexes and deletes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Arbitrary query with multiple objects per result

```py
with Session(engine) as session:
    for (b, a) in session.execute(select(B, A).join(A, B.a_id == B.id)).all():
        print (b, a)
```

#### Relationship without ForeignKey

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, aliased, relationship, remote, foreign

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    b_list = relationship('B', primaryjoin="remote(A.id) == foreign(B.a_id)", back_populates='a')

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer)

    a = relationship('A', primaryjoin="remote(A.id) == foreign(B.a_id)", back_populates='b_list')

with Session(engine) as session:
    for (b,) in session.execute(select(B).join(B.a)).all():
        print (b, b.a_id, b.a, b.a.id, b in b.a.b_list)
```

Comment: I have not tried, but it seems logically correct. However, is there any another way where there is no need to identify `primaryjoin="remote(A.id) == foreign(B.a_id)"`? because I think if I use alias for join, it will not work, is not it?

Comment: I think you are better off just using an ad-hoc query to get the results in that case rather than trying to use `relationship`.  Like in my first example.  It will be faster but inconvenient.

Comment: First example gave me solution, thank you)